# How to use Suspense with RouterProvider in react-router-dom v6.4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-suspense

These are the two components i am having, My question is where do i place the <React.Suspense> component to load the routes as required?

**Navagtion/index.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  RouterProvider,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements
} from "react-router-dom";
import Root from "./Root";

const router = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(Root));

const Navigation = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default Navigation;
```

**Root.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const PublicLayout = React.lazy(() => "../Layouts/PublicLayout");
const PrivateLayout = React.lazy(() => "../Layouts/PrivateLayout");

const Index = React.lazy(() => "../Pages");
const Welcome = React.lazy(() => "../Pages/Welcome");
const Login = React.lazy(() => "../Pages/Login");
const Register = React.lazy(() => "../Pages/Register");

const Root = (
  <Route path="/" element={<Index />}>
    <Route element={<PublicLayout />}>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
    </Route>

    <Route element={<PrivateLayout />}>
      <Route path="/welcome" element={<Welcome />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
);

export default Root;
```

How can i Lazy Load routes inside  component? Where do i wrap All routes from Suspense.

Answer (score 9):

The `remix-run/react-router` [demo](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples/lazy-loading) shows wrapping each lazily imported component in their own `React.Suspense` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const PublicLayout = React.lazy(() => "../Layouts/PublicLayout");
const PrivateLayout = React.lazy(() => "../Layouts/PrivateLayout");

const Index = React.lazy(() => "../Pages");
const Welcome = React.lazy(() => "../Pages/Welcome");
const Login = React.lazy(() => "../Pages/Login");
const Register = React.lazy(() => "../Pages/Register");

const Root = (
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={(
      <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
        <Index />
      </React.Suspense>
    )}
  >
    <Route
      element={(
        <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
          <PublicLayout />
        </React.Suspense>
      )}
    >
      <Route
        path="/login"
        element={(
          <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
            <Login />
          </React.Suspense>
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path="/register"
        element={(
          <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
            <Register />
          </React.Suspense>
        )}
      />
    </Route>

    <Route
      element={(
        <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
          <PrivateLayout />
        </React.Suspense>
      )}
    >
      <Route
        path="/welcome"
        element={(
          <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
            <Welcome />
          </React.Suspense>
        )}
      />
    </Route>
  </Route>
);

export default Root;
```

[React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)

> You can place the `Suspense` component anywhere above the lazy
> component. You can even wrap multiple lazy components with a single
> `Suspense` component.

You could also create a layout route that wraps a `React.Suspense` around an `Outlet` component.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const PublicLayout = React.lazy(() => "../Layouts/PublicLayout");
const PrivateLayout = React.lazy(() => "../Layouts/PrivateLayout");

const Index = React.lazy(() => "../Pages");
const Welcome = React.lazy(() => "../Pages/Welcome");
const Login = React.lazy(() => "../Pages/Login");
const Register = React.lazy(() => "../Pages/Register");

const SuspenseLayout = () => (
  <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
    <Outlet />
  </React.Suspense>
);

const Root = (
  <Route element={<SuspenseLayout />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<Index />}>
      <Route element={<PublicLayout />}>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
      </Route>
      <Route element={<PrivateLayout />}>
        <Route path="/welcome" element={<Welcome />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
);

export default Root;
```

Since the `React.Suspense` component just needs to be higher in the tree than the lazy component, you might also wrap the `RouterProvider` in `Navigation` in the `Suspense` component.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  RouterProvider,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements
} from "react-router-dom";
import Root from "./Root";

const router = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(Root));

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.Suspense>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 2):

I placed it wrapping the Root component on the route element, and it works like this:

**/router/index.jsx**

```
const Root = lazy(() => import('../layout/Root'))

const Home = lazy(() => import('../pages/Home'))
const About = lazy(() => import('../pages/About'))
const Experience = lazy(() => import('../pages/Experience'))
const Projects = lazy(() => import('../pages/Projects'))
const Contact = lazy(() => import('../pages/Contact'))

export const router = createHashRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}><Root /></Suspense>,
    errorElement: <NotFound />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: '/about',
        element: <About />
      },
      {
        path: '/experience',
        element: <Experience />
      },
      {
        path: '/projects',
        element: <Projects />
      },
      {
        path: '/contact',
        element: <Contact />
      }
    ]
  }
])
```